# Display a live feed from usb web camera connected to raspberry pi using node red

Tags: raspberry-pi, node-red

First of all, this is my first time asking question here so correct me if I did anything wrong.

I currently stuck at finding the node that is needed to display live feed from usb web camera which connect to the raspberry pi.

I know there is function node which i will add colour detection code for yellow, template_ui dashboard which I'm using to display live feed video capture by the webcamera but I'm not sure what is the input node and extra stuff i need to add to the flow to make it work.

i tried this from github :

```
[{"id":"86fe9b81.31c418","type":"http request","z":"fafa85fb.98fd68","name":"","method":"GET","ret":"bin","paytoqs":false,"url":"http://192.168.178.21/tmpfs/snap.jpg?usr=admin&pwd=instar","tls":"","proxy":"","authType":"","x":265,"y":343,"wires":[["4068ec45.05b034"]]},{"id":"54d0ea94.c1b9a4","type":"ui_template","z":"fafa85fb.98fd68","group":"73b331f4.a8bda","name":"Display image","order":1,"width":"6","height":"6","format":"\n<img alt=\"HTTP Snap\" src=\"data:image/jpg;base64,{{msg.payload}}\" />\n","storeOutMessages":true,"fwdInMessages":true,"templateScope":"local","x":575.3645515441895,"y":343.6041603088379,"wires":[[]]},{"id":"4068ec45.05b034","type":"base64","z":"fafa85fb.98fd68","name":"","action":"","property":"payload","x":415,"y":343,"wires":[["54d0ea94.c1b9a4"]]},{"id":"3fa57e6a.6819f2","type":"inject","z":"fafa85fb.98fd68","name":"","topic":"","payload":"","payloadType":"date","repeat":"","crontab":"","once":false,"onceDelay":0.1,"x":115,"y":343,"wires":[["86fe9b81.31c418"]]},{"id":"73b331f4.a8bda","type":"ui_group","z":"","name":"HTTP Snap","tab":"d75e440d.a22678","disp":true,"width":"6","collapse":false},{"id":"d75e440d.a22678","type":"ui_tab","z":"fafa85fb.98fd68","name":"Cameras","icon":"camera_alt","order":2}]
```

I still dont know why http request is needed, too be honest.

Comment: The HTTP-request node is because that example is using a network camera not a usb attached camera.